# I am a newbie to DMBS system is it possible to join two Database Systems like SQL and Netezza?

Tags: sql, database, netezza

Is it possible to join two tables from different database systems such as SQL and Netezza using any query language.

Specifically is it possible to achieve a join in AQT.

Is it possible for a tool like AQT ( Advanced Querying Tool) to provide a platform which allows us to connect the tables from these different database systems

Comment: The answer is "yes", but the underlying databases need to support tables linked to other databases (which most do).

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating **linked server** in SQL. But doing so have an overhead on the SQL server from DBA point of view. You need extra privileges to create a linked server.